# compeletly remove unwanted owned applications from account store

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

I am came from android. I am very new to Windows phone. I have download some apps from store. I don't like that apps and uninstalled that apps from my phone. Now when ever I go to My Apps list it showing all the uninstalled apps. I don't want to show that apps. I want to delete completely from My Apps List. Please help me to delete the My Apps List.